# CSS animation-timing-function defaults to ease-in when usingmultiple @keyframes animations with 1<iteration-count

Tags: css, css-animations

I want to create a ball moving left-right-left indefinitely at constant speed.
When using my stylesheet in an HTML page, the following happens:

0-1s: the ball starts moving linearily left to right (as expected);

1-2s: the ball arrives and turns back -- still moving linearily (as expected);

2-3s: the ball starts moving right again, but now with a positive acceleration -- what i assume is the result of a quadratic ease-in (NOT expected);

3-4s: the ball arrives, turns back and has a constant speed (a-t-f: linear) again (as intended, although very unexpected);

4s onward: 2-4s is repeating indefinitely, accelerating when going right, moving at constant speed when going left.

NOTE: this is just a short example, combining the 2 @keyframes rules is not a solution to my problem.

Here is the CSS the relevant CSS:

```
.animated{
  animation-name: left2right, right2left;
  animation-direction: normal;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-delay: 0s, 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: backwards, none;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}
@keyframes left2right {
  0% { left: 0%; }
  50% { left: 100%; }
}
@keyframes right2left {
  0% { left: 100%; }
  50% { left: 0%; } 
}
```

For completeness, here is the non-relevant CSS (which is above the previous code in my style.css):

```
#box{
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid black;
  top: 20%;
  height: 60%;
  left: 40%;
  width: 20%;
}
.ball{
  position: absolute;
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
#one{
  background-color: green;
}
```

And finally, here is the HTML using the stylesheet:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="box">
    <div id="one" class="ball animated"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried using `.animate{animation-timing-function: linear}`, `.animate{animation-timing-function: linear,linear}`, `@keyframes left2right{0%:{animation-timing-function: linear}}`.
I also tried changing 0% to 1% and 50% to 49% in case the overlap between the animations was somehow interfering with eachother. Lastly, i have tried using the `animation:` shorthand.

I tried in two different browsers:

Chrome Version 120.0.6099.217 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Firefox 121.0.1 (64-bit)

All of these produce the same result for me.

Comment: Can you explain more what you want the combined animation to look like? Having two animations running at once both trying to set just one left property doesn’t seem to make sense. What do you want left to be set to at any point in time? Also I note you aren’t using a forwards setting. Also animation delay works just the once.

Comment: @AHaworth My goal is to have left = (t%2 < 1) ? t*100% : (2-t)*100%. The delay is meant to offset the 2nd animation, so that it does its thing (0-50%) exactly when the other one is chilling (its 50-100%).

Comment: @AHaworth The goal is to make a juggling animation, where #one is doing left2right 0-3s, right2left 3-6s, then repeating every 6 seconds; #two is doing right2left 1-4s, left2right 4-7s, then repeating; and #3 is doing left2right 2-5s, right2left 5-8s, then repeating. (note that #2 starts with right2left, so in order to combine them into one keyframes rule would still result in 2 -- twice as long -- functions).

At the same time there is also a separate vertical animation running, but i don't think that is relevant to the complexity.

See that here: https://github.com/nionys/Juggle

Comment: I'm still not clear. Does the first ball spend 2s going from left to right, then sticks at the right for 1s then travels right to left then sticks at the left for 1s then travels left to right in 2s etc or....Please explain where the first ball is to be in each of the 6 seconds.

Comment: @AHaworth it is not supposed to be still at all. its left positions are as follows: 0: 0%, 1: 33%, 2: 67%, 3: 100%, 4: 67%, 5: 33%, 6=0: 0%. [Like this](https://puu.sh/JZ8WI/3faff42a3f.png)

Answer (score 0):

First we create an animation that sends a ball from left to right then back to the left.

```
@keyframes left2right2left {
  0%,
  100% {
    left: 0%;
  }
  50% {
    left: 100%;
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}
```

This will 'do' for ball#1

Ball#2 does exactly the same thing but we don't see it at all for the first second and it starts at the right rather than the left.

We can make sure we don't see it for the first second by giving it an animation that sets its opacity to 1 after 1 second.

We can make sure it starts at the right hand size by giving it a negative animation delay of 3s.

We can then do similar for ball 3.

We can combine everything by giving all the balls two animations, one for the showing after a time and one for setting them going backwards and forwards, with relevant animation-delay.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    .animated {
      animation: show 1s forwards, left2right2left 6s infinite linear;
      animation-delay: var(--start), var(--delay);
    }
    
    @keyframes show {
      0%,
      100% {
        opacity: 1;
      }
    }
    
    @keyframes left2right2left {
      0%,
      100% {
        left: 0%;
      }
      50% {
        left: 100%;
        transform: translateX(-100%);
      }
    }
    
    #box {
      position: absolute;
      border: 1px solid black;
      top: 20%;
      height: 60%;
      left: 40%;
      width: 20%;
    }
    
    .ball {
      position: absolute;
      width: 2rem;
      height: 2rem;
      border: 2px solid black;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      border-radius: 50%;
      opacity: 0;
    }
    
    #one {
      background-color: blue;
      --start: 0;
      --delay: 0s;
    }
    
    #two {
      background-color: orange;
      --start: 1s;
      --delay: -2s;
    }
    
    #three {
      background-color: gray;
      --start: 2s;
      --delay: -4s;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="box">
    <div id="one" class="ball animated"></div>
    <div id="two" class="ball animated"></div>
    <div id="three" class="ball animated"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Note, it looked a bit funny having the balls fly half way out of the right hand side so I put a translateX on them so they stay inside the box.

Comment: You combined the two animations. That does not solve the mistery of why this happens in the first place, and it is not a suitable solution for what i want to do going forward. (see NOTE in the original question -- which i edited to make it more clear)

Comment: Sorry, I thought you wanted each of the 3 balls to continuously move back and forth - just staggered a bit.